# Does Self-Evaluation affect graduation chances?

Tags: discussion

There are a number of questions on this meta to do with the chances of the site's graduation from Beta.  There is a common theme regarding lack of participation in areas other than the main Q&A.  Here is another one.

Does the site self-evaluation affect our chances of graduation?  The number of participants was very small, especially if you compare the count to some of the other beta sites that have gone through the same process in the last couple of weeks.

There is no mention of self-evaluation activity on the Area51 statistics for participation so should we be worried?